# Extimated execution plan raises error with "insert" - while "select into" is fine. Why is that?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this two szenarios (strongly simplified). 
- When executing (F5) everything is fine. 
- When showing the estimated execution plan (Ctrl-L) there is an error: "Invalid object name '#t1'."

Is there any way to use the first szenario (select into) and still being able to "Ctrl-L" and "F5" the code? Something like "delayed validation" in SSIS?

```
--first szenario: select into
if object_id ('tempdb..#t1') is null begin

    select 1 c1 into #t1;

    select * from #t1;

    drop table #t1;
end

--second szenario: insert
if object_id ('tempdb..#t2') is null begin

    create table #t2 (c1 int);

    insert #t2 select 2;

    select * from #t2;

    drop table #t2;
end
```

Comment: Why do you need the estimated execution plan anyway? It is not nearly as complete or accurate as the actual execution plan.

Comment: Estimated Execution plans don't work (well) with objects that don't exist and are created in the same batch, because the Server can't make an estimation on something that doesn't exist. It would have to therefore create the object to do an estimate, and if it's it's doing that it might as well be an Actual execution plan. @SeanLange is right, you should be using an Actual plan. Also.scenario is spelt with a c. ;)

Comment: @Larnu  Ok, I see why a plan estimation would have a problem with estimating for an undefined table. But is there really no work-around to allow plan estimation for a T-SQL that uses the `select into` syntax? It only seems to work when the temp table wasn't dropped at the end.

Comment: Btw, when using a `select into` I would just drop the temp table if it exists. Just before you use the `select into` that will create it. And don't drop the temp table at the end.  Temp tables get dropped automatically anyway after the session closes.  And the plan estimation works while the temp table still exists.

Comment: @Sean Lange: We use estimated execution plans as a first step to check (log-running, long&complex) automated SQL-scripts when they are executed interactively for maintainance (new requirements, performance...). The error thrown with 'select into' can almost always be avoided but it makes things more complicated than nessesary (minimal logging, checking types). I simply don't understand why the algebrizer (or whatever part of SQL-Server throws the error) can handle nonexisting tables when they will be created by 'create table' and it can't when created by 'select into'.

Comment: @Larnu: The Server can make estimations on tables that don't exist as long they will be created via 'create table'. It seems that the Server can't make estimations only on non-existing tables that will be created via 'select into'.

Comment: @LukStorms A temp-table takes place in tempdb. When I don't need it anymore I can drop it. As long your table is small this might be ridiculous - sometimes it's not. But dropping before or afterwards won't change anything to the matter of the question. (My example just shouldn't drop your #t1 in case your session holds one.)

Comment: @Christian4145 Well, instead of a DROP table, you could do a DELETE FROM table.  If you're worried about taking up space.  Then the temp table would still exist and the plan can be estimated. But OK, probably not what you want since you want to estimate the plan before running the SQL.